Pixel not working | Installed a module for the same
I completed a module facebook and instagram in my magento e commerce site for proper tracking of conversion , but pixel is not working it is not available in website, make sure that ad blocker is off any solution facebook and instagram is official extension of meta

where are you adding conversation tracking script
